# Mongo update specific subdoc

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following mongo entry:

```
et = {
languages: [{
    code:  String,
    title: String,
    tools: [{
         description: String,
         mds: [ObjectId]
    }],
}]
//some more stuff
}
```

I now need to update this object and add an new ObjectId to the mds array. I need to specify the language element via the code element and the tools entry via the description parameter.

So far I came up with the following update method with which I can update some element of the correct language entry:

```
ETs.find({
        '_id':mdAttributes.etID,
        'languages':{'$elemMatch':{'code':mdAttributes.language}}
    },{
        '$set':{
            'languages.$.title':'update2.jpg'
         }
    });
```

However I do not know how add an query for the correct tool.

So what my set should make should be something like this:

```
ETs.find({
        '_id':mdAttributes.etID,
        'languages':{'$elemMatch':{'code':mdAttributes.language}}
    },{
        '$set':{
            'languages.$.tools.$.mds': ["newId"]
         }
    });
```

Is there a way to achieve this in mongo?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no. The positional operator doesn't currently work with nested arrays (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/server-831).

You can do it nonetheless by setting the *whole* tools array entry (like you do on your first example, but for the tools array instead of the title field).